# How can you leverage Swift features to refactor this recursive function?

Tags: swift, recursion, nsdictionary

I've been working on a recursive function to extract String values out of JSON data represented as an NSDictionary. The function allows you to do this:

```
if let value = extractFromNestedDictionary(["fee" : ["fi" : ["fo" : "fum"]]], withKeys: ["fee", "fi", "fo"]) {
    println("\(value) is the value after traversing fee-fi-fo");
}
```

And the function implementation looks like this:

```
// Recursively retrieves the nested dictionaries for each key in `keys`,
// until the value for the last key is retrieved, which is returned as a String?
func extractFromNestedDictionary(dictionary: NSDictionary, withKeys keys: [String]) -> String? {
    if keys.isEmpty { return nil }
    let head = keys[0]
    if let result: AnyObject = dictionary[head] {
        if keys.count == 1 {
            return result as? String
        } else {
            let tail: [String] = Array(keys[1..<keys.count])
            if let result = result as? NSDictionary {
                return extractFromNestedDictionary(result, withKeys: tail)
            } else {
                return nil
            }
        }
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Are there some syntactical features related to optional binding in Swift 1.2/2.x that can:

- make this function more succinct
- use less `if` nesting

Comment: This question looks like a good candidate for http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thanks @MartinR, I wasn't aware of that stackexchange silo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of recursion, you can use `reduce` on the `keys` array
to traverse through the dictionary:

```
func extractFromNestedDictionary(dictionary: NSDictionary, withKeys keys: [String]) -> String? {

    return reduce(keys, dictionary as AnyObject?) {
        ($0 as? NSDictionary)?[$1] 
    } as? String
}
```

Inside the closure, `$0` is the (optional) object on the current level and `$1`
the current key. The closure returns the object on the next level
if `$0` is a dictionary *and* has a value for the current key,
and `nil` otherwise. The return value from `reduce()` is then 
the object on the last level or `nil`.

Comment: Oh man I tried for ages to write this as a one-liner with `reduce`. Thanks for showing me the light!

Answer (score 1):

I originally didn't want to just make it without you trying first, but I did it anyways because I love Swift and had fun doing it:

```
func extractFromNestedDictionary(dictionary: [NSObject : AnyObject], var withKeys keys: [String]) -> String? {
    if let head = keys.first, result = dictionary[head] {
        if keys.count == 1 {
            return result as? String
        } else if let result = result as? [NSObject : AnyObject] {
            keys.removeAtIndex(0)
            return extractFromNestedDictionary(result, withKeys: keys)
        }
    }
    return nil
}


extractFromNestedDictionary(["A" : ["B" : ["C" : "D"]]], withKeys: ["A", "B", "C"])
```

A few notes:

- Try to avoid `NSDictionary` and use `[NSObject : AnyObject]` instead, which can be bridged to NSDictionary anyways and is much more Swifty
- When asking a question, try to make a better example than you did there, from your example I wasn't able to know what exactly you want to do.

Comment: Oh don't worry I've been hacking with my own before looking at others' fun contributions. Glad you couldn't resist. :)

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I've updated the method call in the question.

Comment: this will only work if your nested dictionary only has 1 item for each nested dictionary, since you only ever look at head

Comment: What do you feel about the `var` parameter? I chose to make it immutable to be a bit more 'functional'.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Ah, thanks, I think you've pointed out a flaw in my naive function.

Comment: @ybakos Well if I would have to remove 1 item every time, I don't want it to always create a new Array doing so

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't strictly answering the question. But you could just use `valueForKeypath`:

```
let fum = dict.valueForKeyPath("fee.fi.fo")
```

Comment: In many cases this can be a good solution. Note however that it does not work (or even crash) if the keys contain characters which are special for Key-Value Coding like `.` or `@`.

Comment: @mxcl, thanks for slicing right through my function and posting a straightforward alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the best I came up with...

```
func extractFromNestedDictionary(dictionary: [NSObject : AnyObject], withKeys keys: [String]) -> String? {
    if let head = keys.first,
        result = dictionary[head] as? String
        where keys.count == 1 {
            return result
    } else if let head = keys.first,
        result = dictionary[head] as? [NSObject : AnyObject] {
            return extractFromNestedDictionary(result, withKeys: Array(keys[1..<keys.count]))
    }
    return nil
}
```